# Status bar content color not working in VC iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Ok so I know that this code worked in the first VC I used it in, but now it's not working in my remaining VC's

in viewDidLoad:

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

method added in @implementation:

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

**PS**  I have view controller-based status bar boolean set to YES in my MyProject-Info.plist
Also, my current problem shouldn't have anything to do with hierarchies b/c the second VC that I'm trying to use this code in has the exact same setup as the login page that I made it work on.  Its a regular VC embedded in a Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the defaults for the status bar's in all your `ViewController`'s that'd you'd like to set 'white' to a black nav bar. This appears to be a sort of glitch with iOS7, but regardless, it works.